# Clear all the items of a listview- c#

Tags: c#, .net, listview

How can I clear a ListView in C#?

Here's how I populate my ListView:

```
int listViewCounter = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < dtXLS.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    listViewCounter++;

    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
    item.Text = "First item" + listViewCounter;
    item.SubItems.Add("sadad" + listViewCounter);
    item.SubItems.Add("sadad" + listViewCounter);
    item.SubItems.Add("sadad" + listViewCounter);
    item.SubItems.Add("sadad" + listViewCounter);
    LV.Items.Add(item);

    LV.Items[listViewCounter - 1].SubItems[0].Text = listViewCounter.ToString();
    LV.Items[listViewCounter - 1].SubItems[1].Text = "sample1";
    LV.Items[listViewCounter - 1].SubItems[2].Text = "sample2";
    LV.Items[listViewCounter - 1].SubItems[3].Text = "sample3";
    LV.Items[listViewCounter - 1].SubItems[4].Text = "sample4";
}
```

The result will be:

```
1st Column    2nd Column    3rd Column    4th Column    5th Column
1             sample1       sample2       sample3       sample4
```

Cdeez this is the part of my code so that you can see:

```
public void ProcessFunction(RichTextBox rtb1, RichTextBox rtb2, DataTable dtXLS, ListView LV)
{
    int matchlist_counter = 0;


    string[] wordsToRedact = new string[dtXLS.Rows.Count];


    for (int i = 0; i < dtXLS.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        wordsToRedact_counter++;


        wordsToRedact[i] = dtXLS.Rows[i][0].ToString();
        wordsToRedact[i] = Regex.Escape(dtXLS.Rows[i][0].ToString());


        Regex test = new Regex(@"\b(" + wordsToRedact[i] + @")\b", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.Compiled);
        MatchCollection matchlist = test.Matches(rtb1.Text);


        if (matchlist.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < matchlist.Count; j++)
            {
                WordsToRedact words = new WordsToRedact(matchlist[j]);

                HighLighting HL = new HighLighting();
                HL.Highlight_Words(pdfRT, words, Color.Yellow);
                matchlist_counter++;
            }
        }



        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
        item.Text = "First item" + wordsToRedact_counter;
        item.SubItems.Add("sadad" + wordsToRedact_counter);
        item.SubItems.Add("sadad" + wordsToRedact_counter);


        LV.Items.Add(item);
        LV.Items[wordsToRedact_counter - 1].SubItems[0].Text = wordsToRedact_counter.ToString();
        LV.Items[wordsToRedact_counter - 1].SubItems[1].Text = wordsToRedact[i];
        LV.Items[wordsToRedact_counter - 1].SubItems[2].Text = matchlist_counter.ToString();

        matchlist_counter = 0;
    }
}


private void analyzeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listView1.Items.Clear();
    DataTable dtXLS = loadXLS(xls_path);
    WordsToRedactFunc(pdfRT, visfRT, dtXLS, listView1);
    MessageBox.Show("Processing done!", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
```

My question now is how can I clear all of the items every time a specific button click?

Comment: Title doesn't reflect the actual question, no?

Answer (score 6):

Change your code:

```
ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem("First item" + listViewCounter);
item.SubItems.Add("sadad" + listViewCounter);
item.SubItems.Add("sadad" + listViewCounter);
item.SubItems.Add("sadad" + listViewCounter);
item.SubItems.Add("sadad" + listViewCounter);
LV.Items.Add(item);
```

And in button click write like this `LV.Items.Clear();`

Comment: I did that, I don't know what's the problem but the error occurs: InvalidArgument=Value of '3' is not valid for 'index'.

Comment: Cdeez, actually the algo of my codes is this, I have a button that includes populating my listview, after that I want my listview to be clear so that the items in the first click will not include in the second click of the button.

Comment: there is a mistake in the procedure that you are following then. If you are calling LV.Items.Clear() on button click then eventually you will end up the previous items cleared when you are actually trying to append them. Or is it that you want fresh items to be inserted every time?

Comment: Yes I want fresh items to be inserted everytime. To make myself clear, I will post some of the code so that it will be much clearer to you. thanks. Wait I will post it.

Comment: it still got an error: InvalidArgument=Value of '3' is not valid for 'index'., please see my answer post, so that it will be much clearer to you. thanks cdeez.

Comment: Let me make few things clear- First of all the additional code you provided is not required since the problem you have is in the for loop. Second- The code also does not seem wrong. Do this: Insert break points at **every line in the for loop** and see at what iteration and exact location you are getting the error.

Comment: In this line goes the error -> ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem("First item" + listViewCounter);
Error: InvalidArgument=Value of '3' is not valid for 'index'

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to clear your list:

`listView1.Items.Clear();`

To add some new items consider

```
listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] { string1 , string2 , ....}));
```

Answer (score 0):

For all who will encounter the same problem as this, I now figure out what's wrong with my code, and I just want to post it here,

```
private void analyzeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listView1.Items.Clear();
    //I just add this line 
    listviewItem_Counter = 0;  // -> this integer needs to be set as zero because evrytime the analyze button be click it will be use, so it needs to be fresh again!

    DataTable dtXLS = loadXLS(xls_path);
    WordsToRedactFunc(pdfRT, visfRT, dtXLS, listView1);
    MessageBox.Show("Processing done!", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

LV.Columns.Clear() will clear all of the columns, including the headers.

Answer (score -1):

Simply use  [`LV.Clear()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.clear.aspx) .
This will remove all items and columns from the control.